How to animate between two grid template areas?
I have two grid template areas. I need a transition between the two grids. I know you cannot transition it by itself. But maybe someone has a nice solution to my problem. To add a smooth transition. Please provide it in jsx.
grid-template-areas:
    "tile-1 tile-1 ..."
    "tile-1 tile-1 tile-2"
    "tile-3 tile-4 tile-5";

And:
&.reOrder {
    grid-template-areas:
      "tile-1 tile-2 ..."
      "tile-4 tile-5 tile-5"
      "tile-3 tile-5 tile-5";
  }

Here is my codepen.
https://codepen.io/melissa-bos/pen/mdNpYBQ
I already tried it with useSpring but it won't work
